# Python : vi mode when reading from stdin

Tags: python, python-2.7, vi

When I run a program that uses `somevar = sys.stdin.readline()`, I can't use my vi commands (I have `set -o vi` in my .bashrc) when entering text into stdin.  Is there a way to enable this functionality when reading from stdin in a python script? I am using python2.7.

Comment: See: https://pymotw.com/2/readline/ and after that, https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html and https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Comment: But note that the `readline` module only affects `raw_input()`, and has no effect upon `sys.stdin.readline()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `readline` module installed, try it. Here is a code snippet I copied from this [page](https://pymotw.com/2/readline/):

```
import readline

readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
readline.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode vi')

while True:
    line = raw_input('Prompt ("stop" to quit): ')
    if line == 'stop':
        break
    print 'ENTERED: "%s"' % line
```